# Create multidimentional array in swift with different datatypes

Tags: ios, xcode, tree, swift3, dynamic-arrays

this is my first question here so forgive me if it is not very clear.

I am trying to create an array in swift that will store either arrays of arrays or an integer number.
The array is supposed to be a simple representation of the data I will be using which is basically a tree kind of data structure like so...

Array = [ [**[** [2, 3] **]**, **[** 1, 4 **]**, **[** 2 **]**],
          **[** 2 **]**, **[**[2, 5], [6, 1] **]**, 3 ]

In overall the arrays are the branches and the integers are the leaves

I've tried declaring them as optionals like so

```
var test2 = [[[Int]?]?]()
```

Or using typedef's but I still can't get it to work.

Also, it should be possible to add new leaves to any of the arrays

Comment: Why don't you define a tree? It would be much easier.

Comment: var test2 = [Any]()

Comment: @shallowThought I thought on something similar but I was using AnyObject instead of Any. This seems to work fine for the assignment part but like that I miss the autocompletion part this is something I wanted.

Comment: @appzYourLife the tree might work with the autocompletion but is slightly harder for me to understand so it might take a while for me to get it working, but thanks for the idea I will look at it

Comment: Look into Swift's enum. Think of two alternatives, one for leaves with an associated integer, the other for branches with an associated array. Taking this approach you should be able to be precise over what can go into your tree, whereas using `AnyObject` you can put values of the wrong type into your tree.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this array?

Comment: If you want a tree, create a tree. Create a `Node` struct or class with `subtree` and `value` properties. `var value: Int?` `var subtree: [Node]?`

Comment: I am trying to create an accordion using tables (is part of the requirements not use pod and such). I need to display a list of products to the user that will be added programmatically to the list and each product has a different amount of settings.
My plan is to use the array to keep track of how many cells each product setting has in order to hide/display the correct ones

The TableSection will be used for products, then there are rows for the setting category and others for the settings themselves (my problem is with this last one in which I can have a category inside another category)

Comment: @andecoder: as you want to be able to set different types (numbers and arrays), using `Any` is the only option you have beside introducing an own type like mentioned by @Paulw11. Imo @Paulw11 should make this an answer, which you should accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on `enum`, first declare the `enum`:

```
enum Node
{
    case leaf(Int)
    case branch([Node])
}
```

You can now write things such as:

```
let x = Node.leaf(42)
let y = Node.branch([Node.leaf(42), Node.leaf(24)])
```

However this is going to become laborious very quickly. Fortunately Swift allows conversions from literals, so we add:

```
extension Node : ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral
{
    init(integerLiteral value: Int)
    {
        self = .leaf(value)
    }
}

extension Node : ExpressibleByArrayLiteral
{
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Node...)
    {
        self = .branch(elements)
    }
}
```

And with those added we can now write the above two `let` statements as:

```
let x : Node = 42
let y : Node = [42, 24]
```

which is nicer. However if we `print(y)` we get:

```
branch([Node.leaf(42), Node.leaf(24)])
```

If you wish to pretty print that you can add:

```
extension Node : CustomStringConvertible
{
    var description : String
    {
        switch self
        {
            case .leaf(let value):
                    return value.description
            case .branch(let branches):
                    return branches.description
        }
    }
}
```

And now `print(y)` gives you:

```
[42, 24]
```

Finally your example:

```
let w : Node = [[[[2, 3]], [1, 4], [2]], [2], [[2, 5], [6, 1]], 3]
```

which prints as:

```
[[[[2, 3]], [1, 4], [2]], [2], [[2, 5], [6, 1]], 3]
```

You'll want to complete the `enum` type, with predicates such as `isLeaf` etc., but that is the basic idea.

HTH